# How to obtain the bound $\lambda \exp(\lambda^{2}/2)$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, inequality

How is the the bound $$ \int _{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x^{2}/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}} x(\exp(\lambda x)-1)dx \leq \lambda \exp(\lambda^{2} /2)$$ obtained for $\lambda > 0$?

Splitting the integral does not help since $E[X\mathbb 1_{\{X \geq 0\}}] $ is infinite is $X$ is standard normal Gaussian. Furthermore, I know that:

$\lambda x \leq \exp(\lambda x)-1$.

The only way I could use this would be to say

$$ \int _{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x^{2}/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}} x(\exp(\lambda x)-1)dx \leq \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{(\exp(\lambda x )-1)^{2}}{\lambda}\frac{e^{-x^{2}/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}dx$$

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's a printing or copying error but you can show the estimation using $\sqrt{2\pi}$ instead of $2\pi$ by partial integration:

\begin{eqnarray*} \int _{0}^{\infty} \underbrace{\frac{e^{-x^{2}/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}} x}_{u'} \underbrace{(\exp(\lambda x)-1)}_{v}dx
& = & \underbrace{\left. -\frac{e^{-x^{2}/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}(\exp(\lambda x)-1)\right|_0^{\infty} }_{=0}+ \frac{\lambda}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int _{0}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}+\lambda x} dx \\
& \stackrel{square\: compl.}{=} & \frac{\lambda}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int _{0}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{(x-\lambda)^2-\lambda^2}{2}} dx \\
& \stackrel{t=x-\lambda}{=} & \frac{\lambda e^{\frac{\lambda^2}{2}}}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int _{\color{blue}{-\lambda}}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}} dt \\
& \stackrel{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}} dt = \sqrt{2\pi}}{\leq} & \lambda e^{\frac{\lambda^2}{2}}
\end{eqnarray*}